# Why is my launcher icon smaller when placed on the Android desktop?

Tags: android

I have an application built for 1.5 and I am adding higher resolution drawables to support hdpi devices in 1.6 and above.

My original application icon is 48x48.  I created a second launcher icon that is 72x72 and placed it in a res/drawable-hdpi/ directory.

When I install the application on my Nexus One the icon looks good when I view it in the application menu.  But when I place it on the desktop it appears small relative to other icons, my guess is I'm seeing the 48x48 version with no scaling.

These are my two resource directories:

res/drawable/appicon.png
res/drawable-hdpi/appicon.png

Do I need to do something differently either with my directory structure or my manifest file to get things to display correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the application completely, then reinstalled it.  That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked one of my apps that I only have a 48x48 icon for.  The size of the icon in the app drawer and on the home screen is identical on my Nexus One.

Do you have extra whitespace in one of your icons perhaps?

Comment: The icons are created using the same psd, resizing to the right dimensions and then exporting the png.  The problem only arose when I created a 72x72 icon for hdpi devices.  Prior to that the N1 was just scaling my 48x48 icon.  It was workable, but not very pretty.